# Why isn't my document validating as XHTML 1.1 STRICT?

Tags: xhtml, doctype, w3c, xml-attribute, xhtml-1.1

While target="_blank" is deprecated, why is the W3C validator not giving an error about this ? You can paste and check this code int the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="New window will open" target="_blank">Link opens in new window</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Does it mean that XHTML 1.1 supports target=”_blank”, but XHTML 1.0 strict does not? Or is it a bug in the W3C validator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being validated as XHTML **Transitional** rather than **Strict**. If you manually override the doctype to XHTML 1.0 Strict you get this error:

> Error  Line 11, Column 76: Attribute "target" exists, but can not be used for this element.
>
> *…om" title="New window will open" target="_blank">Link opens in new window*

Use this doctype if you want to be strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The transitional schemas still allow certain deprecated elements and attributes, I guess to help people *transition* in steps towards a stricter markup.

**EDIT:**

OK, so the original code was XHTML 1.1 of which there is just one single version (no Strict/Transitional), and according [this FAQ](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#target) the target attribute is indeed not allowed. So I guess this must be a bug in the validator.

Comment: Is it really a bug in w3c validator

Answer (score 2):

It is deprecated but not removed. That's why i think there is problem in validating that.

Answer (score 2):

The [XHTML1.1 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/xhtml-modularization.html#s_targetmodule) shows that the target attribute of an `a` element can be "anything".

Comment: it means XHTML 1.1 support target=”_blank”?

Answer (score 2):

Does it means XHTML 1.1 support target=”_blank” but XHTML 1.0 strict not?

Well, Yes.

If you need a workaround for your problem, then this is one of them. Another option is to use window.open() instead of target="_blank".

Comment: but if i'm working with XHTML 1.1 then can i use target=”_blank”?

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and I got the following error.

Error found while checking this document as XHTML 1.1!

Validation Output: 1 Error

1. Error Line 11, Column 76: there is no attribute "target"

   ….com" title="New window will open" target="_blank">Link opens in new window

The validator is working as of 1/30/2012.  You cannot pass validation using target="_blank"

Replace with this valid portion of code:

onclick="target='_blank';"

Answer (score 0):

While xhtml may support "targrt="_blank", it WILL NOT validate it because it hase been depreciated.  If you don't want to use JS, you will have to use transitional instead of strict in your "document type".